# How to configure javafx numeric Spinner in SceneBuilder 8

Tags: javafx, scenebuilder

I know it's possible to do that in FXML:

```
<Spinner fx:id="spinner" min="0" max="100" initialValue="3" >
  <editable>true</editable>
</Spinner>
```

But I can't find how it's possible to do that in sceneBuilder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spinner was introduced in JavaFX 8. It has no Stylesheet handling like the one in (for ex.) Slider implemented right now, so SceneBuilder don't know the properties that are stylable.

Compare Spinner and for example Slider source code, there is missing a nested StyleableProperties class in Spinner.

Answer (score 2):

I got the same problem, I didn't found Spinner in Scene Build and I put in Scenne Builder manually. This is my code.

1. I have modified .fxml document to put the Spinner in Pane.

   ```
   <Pane fx:id="paneTamano" layoutX="527.0" layoutY="46.0" prefHeight="125.0" prefWidth="141.0" stylesheets="@css.css">
       <children>
           <Spinner fx:id="spinnerTamano" layoutX="17.0" layoutY="49.0" onMouseClicked="#tamano" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="110.0" />
       </children>
   </Pane>
   ```
2. I created an ObservableList at DocumentController.java to give values ​​to the spinner.

   ```
   ObservableList<String> listaTamanos = FXCollections.observableArrayList("Grande", "Mediana", "Pequeña");
   ```
3. Finally insert values in to the Spinner.

   ```
   SpinnerValueFactory<String> valueFactory = new SpinnerValueFactory.ListSpinnerValueFactory<String>(listaTamanos);        
   spinnerTamano.setValueFactory(valueFactory);        
   valueFactory.setValue("Pequeña");
   ```